# Does this look like asbestos glue?

Tags: adhesive, asbestos

I pulled up some carpet and found some brownish glue that's still gummy underneath the pad.  This doesn't appear to look like any of the images of asbestos glue I can find online (it's see-through and not completely black), but I just want to double check.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

AFAIR, asbestos mastic is much more likely with tile (which may itself contain asbestos) - I would not expect it under carpet, other than as a remnant of a prior tile job (no sign of that here.) And, as you have noted, it doesn't look like it.

While you could engage full paranoia (as the folks that make money from it like) and have it tested, you can probably remove it without too much concern, and if it's "gummy" you might want to take a "solvent and wipe up" approach anyway, which would minimize anything getting in the air.